# Is this probability density function computable (seems like a generalized multivariate t-distribution)?

Tags: distributions, density-function

I have obtained an unnormalized probability density function (pdf) for the coefficients of a linear regression model:

$$
f(\boldsymbol{\beta})\propto \mathrm{det}\left [\sum_{i=1}^{N}
(\boldsymbol{y}_i-\boldsymbol{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta})
(\boldsymbol{y}_i-\boldsymbol{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta})^\top \right ]^{-\frac{N}{2}}
$$

where $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ is a $K \times 1$ random vector, $\boldsymbol{y}_i$ is a $J \times 1$ vector, $\boldsymbol{X}_i$ is a $J \times K$ matrix, and $N>K>J$. The first $J$ columns of $\boldsymbol{X}_i$ are an identity matrix $\boldsymbol{I}_{J \times J}$.

It seems like a "generalized multivariate t-distribution" (sorry for abuse of terminology). When $K=J=1$, this is a non-standard univariate t-distribution with $N-1$ degrees of freedom.

I have several questions regarding this pdf:

(1) Is $f(\boldsymbol{\beta})$ the pdf of a known distribution?

(2) Is there a closed-form normalizing term for $f(\boldsymbol{\beta})$?

(3) Is there a closed-form mean value for the distribution implied by $f(\boldsymbol{\beta})$?

Comment: Note that $\Sigma_{i=1}^Nx_ix_i^T = X^TX$.

Comment: @jbowman Does this mean not using the sum operation? I tried to not use the sum operation, but $\boldsymbol{X}_i$ is a matrix so this may need a tensor expression. Also, sorry for a mistake in my initial post. I forgot to add the exponential $^{-\frac{N}{2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Each term in your summation is an [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) of a vector with itself.  Taking $\boldsymbol{h}_i(\boldsymbol{\beta}) \equiv \boldsymbol{y}_i-\boldsymbol{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta}$ allows us to write this outer product in a parsimonious form:

$$\boldsymbol{h}_i(\boldsymbol{\beta}) \otimes \boldsymbol{h}_i(\boldsymbol{\beta}) = (\boldsymbol{y}_i-\boldsymbol{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta}) (\boldsymbol{y}_i-\boldsymbol{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta})^\text{T}.$$

Now, using the [matrix representation of sums of outerproducts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product#Connection_with_the_matrix_product), we can write:

$$\boldsymbol{H}(\boldsymbol{\beta})^\text{T} \boldsymbol{H}(\boldsymbol{\beta}) 
= \sum_{i=1}^N (\boldsymbol{y}_i-\boldsymbol{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta}) (\boldsymbol{y}_i-\boldsymbol{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta})^\text{T}
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
\boldsymbol{H}(\boldsymbol{\beta}) \equiv \begin{bmatrix} 
(\boldsymbol{y}_1-\boldsymbol{X}_1 \boldsymbol{\beta})^\text{T} \\
(\boldsymbol{y}_2-\boldsymbol{X}_2 \boldsymbol{\beta})^\text{T} \\
\vdots \\
(\boldsymbol{y}_N-\boldsymbol{X}_N \boldsymbol{\beta})^\text{T} \\
 \end{bmatrix}.$$

From this we see that the determinant in your expression is the [Gram determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix#Gram_determinant) of the matrix $\boldsymbol{H}(\boldsymbol{\beta})$.  The Gram determinant is non-negative and is strictly positive for values of $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ where the columns of $\boldsymbol{H}(\boldsymbol{\beta})$ are linearly independent.  Consequently, there  is some (possibly improper) density function proportionate to the stated positive power of the determinant.  I have not previously encountered a probability distribution with density proportionate to the power of a Gram determinant of this form, so it is not a distribution I recognise.

In general there is no closed form for integrating the Gram determinant over this parameter space.  There is no closed form for the normalising constantor the expected value of the distribution.  You would need to compute these numerically, which could potentially be quite challenging.

Comment: This is very useful! I guess the integral $\mathrm{det}\left [\sum_{i=1}^{N}(\boldsymbol{y}_i-\boldsymbol{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta})(\boldsymbol{y}_i-\boldsymbol{X}_i\boldsymbol{\beta})^\top \right ]^{-\frac{N}{2}}$ might converge because the Gram determinant is positive and does not infinitely approach zero, and the integral $\int_{a}^{+\infty}x^{-k}dx$ converges when $k>1$ and $a>0$ (rather than $a=0$).